# How to apply a knockback without it looking like teleportation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

So I have the following script which applies force when a player gets hit. I like the speed that the knockback is currently set to, but I would like for the player to move back more smoothly (as in you can see the object slide back) instead of him instantly moving back. Here is the script:

```
 public class meleeAttack : MonoBehaviour
 {
     int speed = 1000; 


     void Start()
     {

     }

     void Update()
     {

     }

     void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
         {

             other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
         }
     }


 }
```

What would be the best approach to achieving this?

Comment: Using the physics system is already a good way to avoid things moving unnaturally. If the movement is too quick though, it will still appear like they're just jumping from one place to another. Effective use of animation on the target object can provide the semblance of speed, without actually requiring the object to move blindingly fast.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what your physics engine does exactly, but from my experience with Box2D, I would expect that `AddForce` adds the force just for the next iteration of physics update. What that means is that your character will gain all the speed within just one update, and it will look instantaneous.

What you could try to do is apply a smaller force for a longer period of time (maybe as long as the two objects are colliding? Or maybe just an arbitrary period of time depending on the type of attack?)

Comment: Did you try playing with different speed values? I bet you can find a speed that will do it for you. If you can't, maybe there's too much friction between the character and the ground and then you either have to change physics material for a bit or do something non-physical.